# Transaction mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, rollback

I need to write into two different mongodb collections using an **'all or nothing'** process. Fyi I use NodeJs in my backend side.

As far as I know MongoDb provides atomicity when it comes to a single collection, but it does not when we need to write into multiple collections.

So I'd like to know a way of emulating this a transaction in **nodejs/mongodb** in order to avoid writing into one collection if the other failed and also getting the possibility of doing a 'roll back' if the second process fails.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB (prior to 4.0) there is no way you can fully implement transactions on database level. However, there are some mechanisms which provides some transactions functionality. You can read about them in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#transaction-like-semantics).

Since MongoDB 4.0, transactions are supported. Very little chage is needed in your current code to support them. There's a new section in the [documentation fully dedicated to the subject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)

Comment: Thanks @JustLogin. The fact is that I have already read all this documentation but I wanted to know if there is another way to emulate it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mochics If you need lots of transactions, you have to use another DB. As far as I know, there are no NoSQL DBs with full transactions support.

Comment: I just need one transaction in a single operation of the whole platform and I cannot change the DB so I'm afraid I'm blocked with it. I'll try to emulate the two phase commit, proposed by MongoDb but I'm not sure if it really works well...

Comment: You may create transactions server-side. In many cases this is the only way.

Comment: MongoDB 4.0 fully supports transactions https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Answer (score 5):

Starting from version 4.0 MongoDB will add support for multi-document transactions. Transactions in MongoDB will be like transactions in relational databases.
For details visit this link:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb?jmp=community

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a library that implements the two phase commit system mentioned above. It might help in this scenario. [Fawn - Transactions for MongoDB](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn)

Answer (score 3):

The transactions for multi-document have been introduced in `MongoDB 4.0` !!!

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions